# AngularJS Directives using different templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is probably going to be a bit complicated, so I will try to keep it as easy as I can.
I have a directive:

```
.directive('configuratorRows', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            garments: '=configuratorRows',
            templateUrl: '&',
            colours: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'assets/tpl/directives/configuratorRows.tpl.html',
        controller: 'ConfiguratorRowsDirectiveController',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

            // Assign our garments to our controller
            controller.garments = scope.garments;
            scope.rows = controller.rows;

            // Invoke our calculation function
            controller.buildRows();
        }
    };
});
```

This directive is in charge of working out how many rows of "garments" should be shown in a particular area. On one of my views I invoke it two times like this:

```
<div configurator-rows="controller.sportswear" colours="controller.colours" ng-if="controller.sportswear.length">
</div>

<div configurator-rows="controller.leisurewear" colours="controller.colours" ng-if="controller.leisurewear.length"> 
</div>
```

So far so good, on this page I get a list of different garments based on their type (leisurewear of sportswear) and everything works as it should.
The template for this directive looks like this:

```
<div class="row flex-xs" ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center flex-xs flex-end" ng-repeat="garment in row track by $index">
        <div class="kit-template" configurator="garment" colours="colours" designs ng-if="garment"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is another directive in here, this just displays an SVG image for each garment in a row.
Now, I have another area (on the same view) which lists **all** garments and displays them slightly differently.
The same rules apply, so I would like to use my **configuratorRows** directive, but the problem is the "template" is different, I want it to look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 total-item" ng-repeat="garment in kit.garments">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 kit-template" configurator="garment" colours="colours" designs></div>

            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <h4 class="total-title">{{ garment.title }}</h4>
                <p>Quantity: <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" type="button" ng-disabled="garment.quantity <= 10" ng-click="modifyQuantity(garment)"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></button> <span class="text-black">{{ garment.quantity }}</span> <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="modifyQuantity(garment, true)"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I started down the route of allowing a templateUrl override, but then I realised that the area where I am placing this directive is also a directive and has functions assigned to each bit (check the Quantity buttons).

So my next option was to make the **configuratorRows** directive without a template and just use ng-transclude instead. The problem with that, is that having more than one **configuratorRows** in a view seemed to mess around with the scope for each one. So in one I might have 4 rows, but in another I might have 2.

Does anyone know how I can get around this problem elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your goal properly, but if you want to change the directive template, in the directive you can do :

```
templateUrl: function(element,attrs){
    return attrs.type==='all' ? 'configuratorRows.all.tpl.html' :  'configuratorRows.single.tpl.html'; 
}
```

Usage:

```
<div type="single" configurator-rows="controller.leisurewear" colours="controller.colours" ng-if="controller.leisurewear.length"></div>
<div type="all" configurator-rows="controller.leisurewear" colours="controller.colours" ng-if="controller.leisurewear.length"></div>
```

Comment: Looks like this was added in Angular 1.3, and if you don't have an IE8 support requirement, this is the better answer. **EDIT** Nevermind, just not in the 1.2 documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know about this useful feature for long time... :P

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do, though it might be a bit more cumbersome to set up than you might like is to create two different template files `configuratorBase.html` and `configuratorAlt.html` and attach those to two different directives which share the scope (that is a non-isolate scope).

```
.directive('configuratorBase', [function() {
    var configuratorBase = {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: '/path/to/configuratorBase.html'
    };
    return configuratorBase;
});
```

Then your configurator directive could look something like:

```
.directive('configurator', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    var configurator = {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: configuratorLink(scope, element, attributes, controllers) {
            /** if evaluating you need the base */
            var template = angular.element('<configuratorBase/>');
            $compile(element.append(template))(scope);
        }
    };
    return configurator;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a "simply different presentation" of the same template structure, you probably need a different css approach (for example, in sass, have a look on the [bem approach](http://getbem.com/introduction/))

If you need a different template structure, instead, you have to choose the template at-runtime (based, for example, on the *templateUrl* property of the scope).

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .directive('tpl', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        type: '@'
      },
      restrict: 'E',
      //templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
      template: function(elem, attr){
        console.log('suca');
        var tpl = '';
        switch((attr.type || '').toLowerCase()) {
            
            case 'heading':
              tpl += '<h1>Heading</h1>';
              break;
            
            default:
              tpl += '<div">Normal Div Element </div>';
        }
        
        return tpl;
      }
    };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<article data-ng-app="test">
  <tpl data-type="heading"></tpl>
  <tpl></tpl>
</article>
```